# In SQLite3, how do I use Datetime('Now') to find datetimes that are more than N days ago?

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I have a table that includes a 'LastUpdated' column that is generated when the row is inserted using Sqlite's `datetime('now')` function.

How do I write a `Select` statement that finds all rows with 'LastUpdated' more than 100 days old?

I think it's a variant of:
`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (DATETIME('Now')-100 Days) > LastUpdated`

But I'm unsure of:

a) How to specify the 100 Days?

b) Whether I can actually compare datetimes like this or if I first have to convert `DATETIME('Now')` to a string?

c) DATETIME('Now') results in UTC time, correct? I think so from my reading of the documentation, but it was a little confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out--I didn't see all the handy modifiers at the bottom of the [SQLite Datetime Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

A bunch of helpful examples there demonstrating addition/subtraction of any datetime unit (years, months, hours, seconds, etc)

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (DATETIME('Now','-100 Days') > LastUpdated`